# Classes and objects aren't being recognized C++

Tags: c++, class

I am just getting into advanced c++ coding and I am having trouble using classes and objects. Basically I am trying to complete a programming exercise from this 
[site](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/12974/), the excersise is "Dungeon Crawl." The goal is to create a game that uses a grid of charecter to play. I am trying to use a class to make the players stats like x-coordinate, and y-coordinate. There is an error left of '.y' must have class/struct/union. This is the code I have. Thanks for any help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

class players {
public:
    int y = 2; //Row
    int x = 3; //Column
    int health = 10;
    int name = "player";

};

void move() {
    switch (getchar()) {
        case 67: //if right arrow pressed
            player.x += 1;
            gameBoard[player.y][player.x] = { 'P' };
            break;

        case 68: //if left arrow pressed
            player.x -= 1;
            gameBoard[player.y][player.x] = { 'P' };
            break;

        case 66: //if down arrow pressed
            player.y -= 1;
            gameBoard[player.y][player.x] = { 'P' };
            break;

        case 65: //if up arrow pressed
            player.y += 1;
            gameBoard[player.y][player.x] = { 'P' };
            break;

    }
 }

bool hasWon = false;
const int boardRow = 5; //makes the games size
const int boardColumn = 7;

char gameBoard[boardRow][boardColumn] = //Defines starting gameboard
{

    {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
    {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
    {'.','.','.','P','.','.','.'},
    {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
    {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.'}

};

void displayBoard() { //Displays the board
    for (int x = 0; x < boardRow; x++) { //Loop for the rows
        int row = x;
        for (int x = 0; x < boardColumn; x++) { //Loop through column
            cout << gameBoard[row][x];
        }
        cout << endl; //New line after each row
    }
}


int main() {
    players player;
    cout << "Please type your name: "; //Takes user name
    cin >> player.name; //changes the name on the object

    while (hasWon == false) { //keeps taking input until player wins
        displayBoard(); //update board
        move(); //check for keys and move
    }
    system("pause"); // pause
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The `scope` of player is the function `main()`  You are trying to use it in `move()`.  You need to pass the variable as a function argument or give it a different scope.

Comment: I recommend you initialize your `players` members in a constructor.

Comment: Prefer to use character literals, like 'C' instead of 67.  Makes the code more readable.

Comment: I recommend you recompile with all warnings enabled and *fix* them, starting at the top. Don't suppress or ignore!

Comment: You are not *moving* the player.  In order to move the player, you need to restore the `'.'` of the previous location.  Otherwise the board will have too many `'P'` in it.

Comment: In your `move` function, you can remove the `gameBoard` assignment to the end of the function, because it is the same in every case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`player` is defined in `main`. Outside of there, code has no idea what it means.

The simplest fix would be to move the line `players player;` out of `main` to somewhere before `move` (preferably at the top, where the rest of your global variables ought to be). Globals are generally a bad idea, but if you've already got a bunch of them, eh...might as well go with it.

A slightly less iffy solution would be to pass `player` by reference to the code that needs it (here, `move`).

(Far better would be to have your `players` class know how to move around, but that would basically involve a rewrite.)

Answer (score 0):

`player` is out of scope in `move()`. As a quick change, pass it as a parameter:

```
void move(players& player) {
...

move(player); //check for keys and move
```

Next step could be redesign of the classes, say make move() a member function of class Player.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to declare the object 'player' before the function 'move'.

Comment: Make sure it's also removed from `main`, so `cin >> player.name;` will configure the global `player` rather than a local one.